# Assigning styling from an array provided as a prop in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a list of items which color is decided by a prop provided to it. The array of colors is cycled through, and I want to change the color of each element according to the color in the array. I'm currently using inline styling but typescript is giving me this error 
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.`

This is the code that I've currently written:

```
<div>
  <div>
    {this.colors.map(color => {
      return (
        <div id={color} class="colorCircle" style={`background-color: ${color}`}>
          test
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure, but you can try `style={{ backgroundColor: color }}`

Comment: Thank you, this put me on the right track - in the end `style={{ "background-color": color }}` worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

`style={{ "background-color": color }}`